# How can I highlight a specific part of a MS powerpoint slide by clicking an action button in another slide?

Tags: vba, microsoft-office, macros, microsoft-powerpoint, presentations

I am creating a presentation using MS Powerpoint. Is there any way that if I click an action button in one slide, I can go to other slide while a specific part of that slide is highlighted or have a rectangle around and also if I close that newly opened page or go to next/previous slide, the changes erase automatically?
Is there any online code or specific documentation available?

Answer (score 0):

Add a new slide directly after the current one.
Make any changes needed to highlight the content as desired.
HIDE the slide.
Now create a GoToSlide action setting on the previous slide and point it at your new highlight slide.

During a show, when you click the shape with the action setting, it'll take you to your highlight slide, then you'll go to the next slide when you press space/left click or whatever to advance slides.

If you don't click the shape with the action setting, PPT will skip over the highlight slide because it's hidden.